# Hide myactivity.xml has more than 80 views, bad for performance

Tags: android

Is it possible to hide this in XML file:
`myactivity.xml has more than 80 views, bad for performance` ?

I have a complicated UI. So, I want to hide this warning. I mean no way to switch UI into ListView, etc.

Comment: I think you need to minimum view's size firstly,not deprecate the warning,it will do harm to your ui performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue here is the layering.  If it has to layer 80 views on top of one another, that is really bad. Otherwise, that is a LOT to manage

You can see just how bad your UI performance is by using the Android tools in Developer Options > Debug GPU overdraw (on) and Show Surface updates to On. That will show you the performance issues.

Now to fix them, custom view XML'scontaining your subviews are the way to go.

Code maintainability is really important here. Right now a single one line change can screw up everything whereas with custom loaded subviews you minimize this greatly and ask a bit less of the OS at the onset potentially.

Comment: My UI haven't got bad performance:) This is code is already tested on published app for several years. So, I just want to hide this annoying message.

Comment: Nope no way to hide those kinds of warnings, but why would you want to? Its trying to help you make better coding and other decisions for app quality.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide/ignore it by adding `tools:ignore="TooManyViews"` to the view that is making that error. For example:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
...
</LinearLayout>
```

will be

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:ignore="TooManyViews">
...
</LinearLayout>
```

Note that this just hides the Lint warning and doesn't do anything else.